# Visual Studio: Is there a summary of #define constants for each solution configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a large solution, with dozens of projects. There's roughly 5 configurations, each loading a certain set of #define constants (such as DEBUG, TRACING, etc...) Is there a way to see in a summary table which compiler constants are active at a given time for each project?

I'm thinking a grid, like this:

```
Prj/Conf      CFG1                  CFG2                     CFG3
Prj1    (DEBUG,TRACING)        (DEBUG,PERFTEST)
Prj2    (TRACING)
Prj3                            (Prj2Const)               (PERFTEST)
```

Comment: Are you searching for the Configuration Manager, you acces as last entry in your configuration selection menu next to your run button in VS?

Comment: When you look at the config manager, it doesn't say which constants are loaded for each project. Or does it?

Comment: Nope, you're right it doesn't show you the constants. Only the active configurations and platforms.

Comment: Worst case, you can probably parse it from the csproj?

Comment: Argh! Parse the file myself? Surely the world has contrived a way to make my life easier?

Comment: Well, you're a programmer right?  Make one! :D

Comment: @Carlos: it's XML. It's not that tough.

Comment: There's something about writing a program in order to write a program that jars me. But you're right, the XML should be parsed easily...